Calculate the derivative of the modulus of the complex matrix
Could you please advise me on how to calculate the derivative of the modulus of the complex matrix or suggest me related references for this problem?
In particular, given matrics $A\in \mathbb{C}^{1\times M}$, $ B=diag([e^{j\theta_1}, e^{j\theta_2}, \cdots, e^{j\theta_M}]) \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$, and $D \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times 1}$, where $A$ and $D$ are independent of $\theta_i, \forall i$. Let us define $E=|ABD|^2$. How to calculate $\frac{\partial E}{\partial{\theta_i}}$?
I got stuck right at the beginning with the modulus.
Many thanks.

Depends on what norm is  |ABD|

@ Roland F: $ABD \in \mathbb{C}^{1\times1}$, i.e., a (scalar) complex number, then $|ABD|$ will be the modulus of a complex number.

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\k{\boxtimes}
\def\h{\odot}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Real#1{\op{\sf Real}\bR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\GLR#1{\g{\LR{#1}}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$
Let's use a convention wherein
matrices are denote by uppercase letters,
vectors by lowercase letters,
and scalars are denoted by Greek or Caligraphic letters. And to avoid confusion with differential operators, change the column vector name $D\to c$.
These conventions change the problem variables from $\lbrace A,B,D,E,\t\rbrace\to\lbrace a^T,B,c,\E,x\rbrace$
Defining a few more variables
(note that the exp function is applied element-wise)
$$\eqalign{
\def\E{{\cal E}}
b &= \exp(ix),\;B = \Diag b &\qiq &db &= b\h i\,dx= iB\,dx \\
& & &db^* &= -iB^*\,dx^* \\
\phi &= a^TBc \;\equiv\; ac^T:B \qq&\qiq &d\phi &= {ac^T}:dB \\
}$$
allows us to write your objective function and calculate its derivative
$$\eqalign{
\E &= \phi^*\phi \\
d\E
 &= \phi^*\;{d\phi} &\q+\q \g{\phi\;d\phi^*} \\
 &= \phi^*\;\c{d\phi} &\q+\q \g{conjugate} \\
 &= \phi^*\;\c{ac^T:dB} &\q+\q conj \\
 &= \phi^* ac^T:\Diag{db} &\q+\q conj \\
 &= \phi^* \diag{ac^T}:\g{db} &\q+\q conj \\
 &= \phi^* \diag{ac^T}:\GLR{iB\,dx} &\q+\q conj \\
 &= \bR{i\phi^*B^T\diag{ac^T}}:dx &\q+\q conj \\
}$$
If $x$ is $\sf Complex$ then the derivatives
(in the Wirtinger sense) are
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\E}{x}   &= +i\phi^*B^T\diag{ca^T} \\
\grad{\E}{x^*} &= -i\phi\:B^H\diag{c^*a^H} \\
}$$
However, if $x$ is $\sf Real$ then $\,dx^*=dx\,$ and one can combine conjugate terms in the differential, yielding an ordinary ($\sf Real$) derivative
$$\eqalign{
d\E &= 2\Real{i\phi^*B^T\diag{ca^T}}:dx \\
\grad{\E}{x} &= 2\Real{i\phi^*B^T\diag{ca^T}} \\
}$$
I assume that the latter result is what you intended.
Translating this back to the original variable names yields
$$\eqalign{
\grad{E}{\t}
 &= 2\Real{i\LR{ABD}^*B^T\diag{DA}} 
\\\\
}$$

In the derivation, a colon was used for the Frobenius product, which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B^*:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \lbrace {\sf Frobenius\;norm} \rbrace \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{A+C}:B &= A:B \;+\; C:B \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
\Diag a:B &= a:\diag B \\
}$$

Thanks for your nice answer.

In this case you get sums over component products with products ov the complements with exponentials of the differences, e.g. in Mathematica code
  n = 4;
  X[x_ , n_] := Array[(Subscript[x, #] &), n]
 
  M = X[x, 4] .DiagonalMatrix[E^Subscript[\[Theta], #] & /@ Range[4]] . X[u, 4]

$$ M= e^{\theta _1} u_1 x_1+e^{\theta _2} u_2 x_2+e^{\theta _3} u_3 x_3+e^{\theta _4} u_4 x_4$$
$$\bar{M}=M\text{/.}\, \left\{\text{x$\_$Subscript}:\to \bar{x}\right\}$$
$$\text{MM}=\text{Collect}\left[\text{Expand}\left[M \bar{M}\right],\left(u_{\text{$\#$1}} x_{\text{$\#$1}}\&\right)\text{/@}\text{Range}[4]\right]\text{/.}\, \left\{\overline{\theta _{\text{i$\_$}}}:\to -\theta _i\right\}$$
$$\begin{align}&u_1 x_1 \left(e^{\theta _1-\theta _2} \overline{u_2} \overline{x_2}+e^{\theta _1-\theta _3} \overline{u_3} \overline{x_3}+e^{\theta _1-\theta _4} \overline{u_4} \overline{x_4}+\overline{u_1} \overline{x_1}\right)\\&
+u_2 x_2 \left(e^{\theta _2-\theta _1} \overline{u_1} \overline{x_1}+e^{\theta _2-\theta _3} \overline{u_3} \overline{x_3}+e^{\theta _2-\theta _4} \overline{u_4} \overline{x_4}+\overline{u_2} \overline{x_2}\right)\\&
+u_3 x_3 \left(e^{\theta _3-\theta _1} \overline{u_1} \overline{x_1}+e^{\theta _3-\theta _2} \overline{u_2} \overline{x_2}+e^{\theta _3-\theta _4} \overline{u_4} \overline{x_4}+\overline{u_3} \overline{x_3}\right)\\&
 +u_4 x_4 \left(e^{\theta _4-\theta _1} \overline{u_1} \overline{x_1}+e^{\theta _4-\theta _2} \overline{u_2} \overline{x_2}+e^{\theta _4-\theta _3} \overline{u_3} \overline{x_3}+\overline{u_4} \overline{x_4}\right)\end{align}$$
The square has a relatively simple form of derivative
$$  \partial_{\theta _1}  \text{MM} = u_1 x_1 \left(e^{\theta _1-\theta _2} \overline{u_2} \overline{x_2}+e^{\theta _1-\theta _3} \overline{u_3} \overline{x_3}+e^{\theta _1-\theta _4} \overline{u_4} \overline{x_4}\right)+\overline{u_1} \overline{x_1} \left(-e^{\theta _2-\theta _1} u_2 x_2-e^{\theta _3-\theta _1} u_3 x_3-e^{\theta _4-\theta _1} u_4 x_4\right)$$
For simplicity the angles are imaginary implicetly.The square root gets itself as denominator, .

Thanks for your approach.
